# User control displaying data which refreshes every 0.125 seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, databinding

I have the following data bindings set up:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridReflections" Width="auto" MaxWidth="1570" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0,0,240,0">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ColourSet}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding FontWeight}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bearing (PLL)" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding BearingPLL, Mode=OneWay}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Bearing (°)" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding BearingDegrees, Mode=OneWay}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Subtended (PLL)" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding SubtendPLL, Mode=OneWay}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Subtended (°)" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding SubtendDegrees}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Range" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding Range, Mode=OneWay}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Intensity" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding Intensity, Mode=OneWay}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding Time, Mode=OneWay}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Which is linked in the code behind as such:

```cs
private void UpdateUserInterface()
{
    if (ReflectionsReported != null)
        ReflectionsReported.Clear();
    ReflectionList reflectionDatas;
    for (ReflectionCount = 0; ReflectionCount < SmallestArray(); ReflectionCount++)
    {
        reflectionDatas = new(ReflectionCount);
        ReflectionsReported.Add(reflectionDatas);
    }
    labelMarkers.Content = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Marker][0];
    labelReflections.Content = dataGridReflections.Items.Count;
}
```

And the ReflectionsList is defined as:

```cs
public ReflectionList(int i) : base()
{
    ColourSet = ReflectionsUC.normal;
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
    ReflectionData reflr = new()
    {
        BearingPLL = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Bearing][i],
        BearingDegrees = Math.Round((decimal)Convert.ToInt32(Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Bearing][i]) / 65536 * 360, 3),
        SubtendPLL = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Subtend][i],
        SubtendDegrees = Math.Round((decimal)Convert.ToInt32(Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Subtend][i]) / 65536 * 360, 3),
        Intensity = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Intensity][i],
        Range = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Range][i],
        Time = DateTime.Parse(Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Time][0]).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    };
```

With each value defined as:

```cs
public class ReflectionData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _bearingPLL;
    private decimal _bearingDeg;
    private string _subtendPLL;
    private decimal _subtendDeg;
    private string _intensity;
    private string _range;
    private string _time;
    public string BearingPLL { get { return _bearingPLL; } set { if (_bearingPLL != value) { _bearingPLL = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public decimal BearingDegrees { get { return _bearingDeg; } set { if (_bearingDeg != value) { _bearingDeg = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public string SubtendPLL { get { return _subtendPLL; } set { if (_subtendPLL != value) { _subtendPLL = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public decimal SubtendDegrees { get { return _subtendDeg; } set { if (_subtendDeg != value) { _subtendDeg = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public string Intensity { get { return _intensity; } set { if (_intensity != value) { _intensity = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public string Range { get { return _range; } set { if (_range != value) { _range = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public string Time { get { return _time; } set { if (_time != value) { _time = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The update user interface method gets triggered every time the Reflections.Revolution gets filled with new data.
Is there a better / easier way for me to do this with minimal processing / memory usage, understanding I do have a lot of data here which is updating once every 0.125 seconds.
The end result is this:
[image: Working application]